# How to control the execution order of the same event?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, extensions, plugin-events

I would like to know if it's possible to control the order of the execution of the same event in several plugins.
For example, I have the event *event1* in 2 plugins, and I want the *plugin1* execute the event after the *plugin2*

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just order the plugins in plugins manager in the same way you want them to execute. However, it is best practice to keep the even triggers execute in an independent way.